# Access named modules in require built bundle from webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, requirejs

This is probably trivial however I am finding it difficult to achieve.

I have a r.js built bundle (`bundle.js`)

```
define('utils/alpha',{value:"alpha"});
define('utils/beta',{value:"beta"});
define('index',['utils/alpha', 'utils/beta'], function(alpha, beta) {
    console.log('values for', alpha.value, beta.value);
});
```

Which is then required inside webpack entry file (`entry.js`)

```
var app = require('./bundle');
console.log('running example app', app);
```

In the webpack entry file (`entry.js`) I tried to `require('utils/beta')` but that results in webpack error `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'utils/alpha'`

Is this method of accessing `utils/alpha` and `utils/beta` even permitted?

Comment: I would begin reading the resolve documentation here: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/
Usually the `bundle` terminology is used for a Webpack-generated (or, bundled) file, but your description sounds like the requirejs is placed inside it.

Comment: @kyranjamie Webpack is able to consume AMD modules when they are stored as one module per file. However, as per the AMD spec, it is possible to put multiple AMD modules inside a single file, so long as the modules are named (i.e. their `define` calls must have the module name as the first argument). The OP here created the file (`bundle.js`) by using `r.js` but that's not important. The OP could have hand-coded `bundle.js`. What is important is that `bundle.js` is a correct way  to organize AMD modules. The question is whether Webpack can consume such files.

Comment: Thanks @Louis, that sums up my question.

Comment: @kyranjamie, I did spend extensive amount of time reading webpack documentation and searching for everything with define and webpack with no luck.

Comment: This is the closest discussion I found on webpack forum.
https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/628